# ionic - how to route to targeted template correctly?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to build an app using the template from [here](https://github.com/benevolentprof/ionic-tabs-starter-angular-style/tree/extending-starter). I'm trying to make a login page but somehow the rendered template isn't the one I wanted.

Here's the login.route.js I made based on the [layout.route.js](https://github.com/benevolentprof/ionic-tabs-starter-angular-style/blob/extending-starter/www/layout/layout.route.js)

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('starter.login')
        .run(appRun);

    appRun.$inject = ['routerHelper'];

    function appRun(routerHelper) {
        routerHelper.configureStates(getStates());
    }

    function getStates() {
        return [
            {
                state: 'login',
                config: {
                    url: '/login',                      
                    templateUrl: 'login/login.html'
                }
            }
        ];
    }
})();
```

and here's the app.module.js

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('starter', [
            /* Shared modules */
            'ionic',
            'starter.core',
            'starter.login',
            'starter.layout',
            /* Feature areas */
            'starter.account',
            'starter.chat',
            'starter.dash'
        ]);
})();
```

The rendered display for this is the tab layout. When I removed the other modules, leaving only `ionic, starter.core, starter.login`, the rendered display is a blank page. However, when I changed the `templateUrl` in `layout.route.js`, it renders the page I wanted.

```
function getStates() {
        return [
            {
                state: 'tab',
                config: {
                    url: '/tab',
                    abstract: true,                 
                    templateUrl: 'login/login.html'
                }
            }
        ];
    }
```

How do I route to `login/login.html` from `login.route.js`?